# In Wordpress, how to add taxonomy to theme created post type?

Tags: wordpress

The theme I'm using includes a custom post type. I need to add categories and tags to this post type. To avoid editing the theme or creating a child theme I created a simple plugin that I thought would add the taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'gp_register_taxonomy_for_object_type' );
function gp_register_taxonomy_for_object_type() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'service' );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'service' );
};
```

I tried `init` instead of `plugins_loaded` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `admin_init` was the golden ticket here:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'gp_register_taxonomy_for_object_type' );
function gp_register_taxonomy_for_object_type() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'service' );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'service' );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll see that the `plugins_loaded` action is triggered before the theme is loaded. The first action available for themes to hook into is the `after_setup_theme` action.

Have a look at the [wp-settings.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php) file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your function.php

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_taxonomy_for_new_post_type' );
function register_taxonomy_for_new_post_type() {
    register_taxonomy_for_new_post_type( 'post_tag', 'post_type_name' );
    register_taxonomy_for_new_post_type( 'category', 'post_type_name' );
}
```